# How to use Google Maps API to determine bounds of GeoJSON MultiPolygon before adding to map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to pan and zoom map using map.fitBounds() with a bounds object of a GeoJSON multipolygon without first adding it to the map.

I can determine a mapped feature's bounds by using map.data.addGeoson() to add geoJSON multipolygon to map, then grabbing feature w/ map.data.getFeatureById() and using processPoints() from this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dragndrop.

But, like I said, I want to pan and zoom to the multipolygon without first mapping it. I'm trying to frame markers contained within the multipolygon to provide user with more context without immediately pan/zoom to the marker bounds, which could be to a zoom level that does not provide a user enough context. See http://brookfieldlogisticsproperties.com/available-properties. Compare using select filters to drill into state of Utah vs. drilling through the map.

One approach would be to iterate over a GeoJSON MultiPolygon coordinates with the constructors for google.maps.Data.MultiPolygon, google.maps.Data.Polygon, etc. This seems rather unpleasant.

Comment: I'm not sure what  you mean by "I want to pan and zoom to the multipolygon without first mapping it", do you just want to leave the polygon(s) hidden? Can you calculate the bounds off-line and put them in the GeoJSON as a property of the polygon?

Comment: .fitBounds() automatically pans and zooms the map accordingly, so I guess I could have omitted that detail. Regarding calculating bounds offline, I guess I could do that, but not sure how nor if I'd want to add additional logic elsewhere. The platform allows authors to source GeoJSON and plug it into a CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Data-layer must not be drawn on a map.

`map.data` is a built-in Data-layer that will be drawn on a map, to create a Data-Layer without drawing anything simply use

```
new google.maps.Data()
```

So the workflow would be:

```
var 
    //create a map
    map     = new google.maps.Map(someNode,options),
    //create bounds
    bounds  = new  google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
    //create data-layer
    data    = new google.maps.Data();

//add geoJson to the data-layer
data.addGeoJson(yourGeoJson); 

//process the points via the linked function  
processPoints(data.getFeatureById('idOfTheFeature').getGeometry(), 
              bounds.extend,
              bounds);

//set the bounds of the map
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```